# How can I get all the URLs (outside of Facebook) a Facebook user liked via a Like button embedded in an external site?

Tags: facebook, api, button, facebook-like

I tried several options:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes ,
https://graph.facebook.com/me/links
and a couple of FQL queries - but none returned Likes a user makes via Like buttons on external sites.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You just take the [Extended Permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) of [user_likes](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/), you will get what you are looking for....

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work for me. og:type=article objects don't appear in this request.

Answer (score 0):

I think that user_likes only give you the permission to see all real objects that the user likes:
a movie,a musician...
if a page is tagged as article for example:

it won't be shown in the likes request
https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes
cause there is no object in the social graph for it:
"Note that the Open Graph protocol is currently designed to support real-life objects. If your URL is a piece of content — such as a news article, photo, video, or similar — you should set og:type to article (see below). Pages of type article do not have publishing rights, **and will not show up on user's profiles because they are not real world objects**."
(http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)

I am also looking for the same api request, I'll let you know if I'll find it...

Editing:
Ok I asked this question on Facebook:
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=94745
and there is no way of doing that.